# Why does'nt an inner class extend outer class's super class? And is there any way to do this?

Tags: java

I have two base classes, and a subclass extending one base class with an inner class extending the other class.

Base Classes:

```
public class B1 {}

public class B2 {}
```

Subclass:

```
public class A extends B1{

    class B extends B2{}

}
```

Method:

```
execute(B1 b) {
    ..do something
}
```

Call:

```
A a = new A();

A.B inner = a.new B();

execute(inner);
```

This is failing. Does the inner class not extend the outer class's super class? Is there a way in the inner classes constructor to call the outer class's constructor?
Say something like this (failing now..)

```
B() {
    super();
    A()/outer();
}
```

Modification with static method:

```
public class A extends B1{

    static B getInner() {
        return new B();
    }

    static class B extends B2{}

}
```

Call to static method:

```
A.B inner = A.getInner();
```

Comment: At the moment when you construct an inner class instance, the outer class instance already should exist. What kind of construction could you expect?

Comment: That's really a good point. Say if i had a static method in subclass which returns an instance of the inner class, would it make a difference?

Comment: I think that you'd be better off explaining, simply and clearly, what it is that you're trying to achieve, rather than how you can force the current square peg through the round hole. What are you trying to do which has led you to try inner classes as a solution?

Comment: I am trying to circumvent the multiple inheritance rule, to find out if there is any way i could do so. And if possible how would it behave. This is for no specific reason just curiosity.

Comment: You cannot circumvent the multiple inheritance rule, that's the point of the language specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, an inner class cannot extend the outer class' superclass.

You clarified in a comment that you want to circumvent the multiple inheritance rule.  Although Java classes do not directly support multiple inheritance, Java 8 introduced [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) for interfaces, which may satisfy the desire for multiple inheritance in certain situations.

Answer (score 5):

No, and Java doesn't have multiple inheritance. So if an inner class did extend the outer class (or the outer class' super class) then `class B extends B2{}` would be illegal.